# Runtime error in Release mode in OpenCV 2.4.2 under VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, linker-errors, runtime-error, runtime.exec

Compilation of my code in both modes debug and release is successful. Debug mode execute and works fine, but when i execute release mode, it says "the application was unable to start correctly 0x80000003".

What is this error and why debug mode works fine but not release. 
DLLs for debug and release are present in the same directory name "bin". "lib" for both modes also placed in the same directory.

I tried to solve it many ways but not succeeded ? Guide me how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: DEbug your application and find out the offending line.

Comment: I don't have any issue in my code. I am just using 3 lines of code. Kindly read my post in the Frank Boyne answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why debug mode works fine but not release

Thre can be many reasons why one build works while another doesn't.  The shape and size of data structures can be different because of `#ifdef` or because the compiler emits different code, the code being executed can be different - again because of constructs like `#ifdef` or because of the code the compiler is emitting.

That can matter when you've got code with a bug in it.  Let's say you've got a bug that miscalculates the length of an array (or the size of a structure or whatever).  You do some pointer arithmetic and write some data into memory using that pointer - only you're writing to the wrong place.  Whether that mistake breaks your program may depend on what was in the memory you overwrote.

If you're lucky your program crashes almost immediately because what you overwrote was important to some code executed immediately after your bug.  If you're only a little bit lucky your program crashes some time later in a completely different part of your program because what you overwrote was important to code far away from your bug.  If you're really unlucky your program doesn't crash at all until several years later when a completely unrelated change moves things around in memory so now what you are overwriting suddenly *is* important.

There are lots of other possible causes of what are sometimes called [Heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)

> What is this error

One place to look for errors like 0x80000003 is the file WinError.h which you'll find in the SDK you are using (either the one that came with Visual Studio 2010 or one you installed later).  Look in WinError.h and you'll find that that `E_INVALIDARG` is defined to be `_HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80000003L)`.

That doesn't necessarily help though because we we don't know enough about what is returning that error or why it is returning that error or even that your 0x80000003 is in fact an E_INVALIDARG - it could be some other error with the same value, or  some piece of code mis-using E_INVALIDARG or something else.

Another possibility is that 0x80000003 is a [hard-coded breakpoint exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) being thrown - most likely because your program has got to one of those "this should never happen" places where the only thing that makes sense is to throw an exception and crash.  If you look in NtStatus.h (in the same place as you found WinError.h) you'll find that `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` is defined to be `((NTSTATUS)0x80000003L)`

> how to solve this issue

The trick is to figure what is causing the 0x800000003 (and where in your code it is happening) so you can narrow down why it is happening.  Most likely it's an exception but why jump to conclusions?

You can run a release build inside the debugger just as you would run a debug build - that is, build the code using the Release target and then press F5 or Debug | Start Debugging.  Look in the Output Window and you may see some information that will help you interpret the error.

You can also use the Debug | Exceptions menu to add a new Win32 Exception with the value 80000003 and set that up to break when thrown rather than to break when unhandled.  That way you should stop in the debugger when that exception is thrown (if it is in fact thrown).

Of course it could be that even running your program within a debugger is enough to change things so your problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed guidance and solution. But I don't have any error in code. I am just using 3 lines code that is load image from file and show that image using opencv. So it means there is no prob in code. debug mode shows the image as it should be. but when i run in release mode it gives me that error. I am using the pre-compiled libraries of OPencv 2.4.2. Is there any bug in OpenCV or something else happening.

Comment: I have also tested my code by creating new project, but got same error. Actual compilation is ok. nothing is wrong.. but the issue when we execute the exe file. The worst thing is, I can't even check this error from anywhere not from event viewer or debug etc. I think something wrong in dll. ?

Comment: This is the error using debuging.

Cannot find or open the PDB file
First-chance exception at 0x77cd6fcb in test2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000128.
R6034
An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.

Comment: yea the issue is solved by coping tbb.dll to sys32 folder. Actually when I coppied all tbb files, this file was asked me to overite I thought this might be a default system file. I selected No overite. So, the issue happened. Now solved. Thanks.